# How can I cast an array stored as string in MySQL table to integer array in PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, type-conversion, dbeaver

I'm trying to import a MySQL table to a new PostgresSQL(14) table, using DBeaver. Seems like JSON values and int arrays are all stored as string.

One of the columns has values like "[1,2,3,4,...]"

So far this is what I'm looking at.

| Source Type | Target Type |
| --- | --- |
| bigint | numeric |
| timestamp | timestamp |
| varchar (100) | text |
| varchar(255) | text |
| varchar (100) | text |
| timestamp | timestamp |
| timestamp | timestamp |
| timestamp | timestamp |
| varchar (255) | text |
| varchar (24) | text |
| varchar(255) | text |
| varchar (50) | text |
| varchar (150) | text |
| bigint | bigint |
| tinyint | bool |
| tinyint | bool |
| longtext (65535) | `int4range`? |
| varchar (20) | text |
| varchar (50) | text |
| varchar (50) | text |
| text(65535) | text |
| longtext(65535) | text |
| tinyint | int4 |
| int | numeric |
| varchar (150) | text |
| bigint | numeric |
| varchar (10) | text |
| longtext (65535) | jsonb |

Another thing is when I try interger[] as type. DBeaver throws this error;
`Can't find specified data type by name: 'integer[]'`
`int4range` is can be seen in the datatype list, but I'm not sure if that is what I think.

I figured out there is a transform section which I can write an expression, but I'm not sure what kind of expression can be written here, I couldn't find anything about it.

I've found a resource mentioning JEXL but not sure what that is. How this can be achieved? With or without DBeaver?

PS. Instead of using varchar(n), I'll be using constraints for text types.

Same table above, just for the reference;

[image: mysql to postgres type casting]

Comment: int4range is a range data type. That is very different from a longtext and a range is not an array anyway.

Comment: @FrankHeikens should've been JSONB then?

Comment: Do you store json in that field or not? There is a wide range of data types, you should check your data and find the best match: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype.html

Comment: I've checked tried  "integer[]" but didn't worked. Maybe I did something wrong, its just string exactly like this [1,2,3,4]

`Can't find specified data type by name: 'integer[]'`